# Perl: Creating new variables inside a loop

Tags: perl, loops

I have code like the following:

```
 my $player_2ubid = grep { $_->ubid eq "2ubid" } @{$room_members };
 my $player_3ubid = grep { $_->ubid eq "3ubid" } @{$room_members };
 # ....
 my $player_11ubid = grep { $_->ubid eq "11ubid" } @{$room_members };
```

To avoid repetition, I want to go for a loop

```
for my $i ( 2 .. 11 ){
my $player_.$i.ubid = grep { $_->ubid eq "$i.ubid" } @{$room_members };
}
```

However this produces syntax error:

```
Can't modify concatenation (.) or string in scalar assignment at ***.t line 100, near "};"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `"$i.ubid"` -> `$i."ubid"` or `"${i}ubid"`

Comment: @KoVadim thanks. I am suspecting that $player_.$i.ubid may also be in trouble

Comment: I think, you should study word "array".

Comment: Variable names with a number at the end is a **really** good indication that your code is designed badly. This should be an array or a hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to write `$i."ubid"` or `"${i}ubid"` instead of `"$i.ubid"`.

And I'd use an hash like:

```
my %player_ubid;
for my $i ( 2 .. 4 ){
    $player_ubid{$i} = grep { $_->ubid eq $i."ubid" } @{$room_members };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the variable in wrong way, you can use hash instead of it.

But if you want to achieve in similar fashion, do it in this way

```
for my $i ( 2 .. 11 ){
  my $var = "player_".$i."ubid";
  $$var = grep { $_->ubid eq $i."ubid" } @{$room_members };
}
```

$$ creates the variable of the value inside the variable, just like in php.

Comment: `$$var` will produce warnings when `use strict`, right? And, it is [almost always a bad idea](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html). But I understand you provided it as another way to solve the problem.

Comment: What will be the scope of the variables created this way?

Comment: If you use strict then it is not a good approach, because scope of those variable remain inside the loop and also strict will produce warings when we use $$.

Comment: To make this clear: `strict` has nothing against the `$$var` – but it forbids using the *names* of variables as references. Using names as references is a bad programming practice (see varnie's link), and (in Perl) can only create *global* variables, which have *infinite* scope.

Comment: @amon It is not true that only global variables can be created. Try `my $var = 'Foo::foo';`

Comment: @TLP I do not understand your comment – using the fully qualified name for symrefs doesn't change the scope of the resulting variable. It is still global.

Comment: "To make this clear: strict has nothing against the $$var – but it forbids using the names of variables as references."  - I'm probably misunderstanding, but isn't that exactly what $$var does?

Comment: @Disco3 You can use normal references, which behave similar to pointers: `use strict; my $x = 42; my $var = \$x; $$var = "hello world"; say $x` – output: `hello world`. The `$$var` doesn't neccessarily have to use “varvars” or “symbolic references”.

Comment: @amon Ah, I see what you mean. You mean it cannot be lexically scoped. I assumed you meant that all variables created would belong to `main::`.